ANR exception bottomsheet not opening for first time @
fun toggleRunning(context: Context) {
    if (_isStartButtonBlurred.value) return

    val isStarting = timeElapsed.value <= 0
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val currentState = _uiState.value

        val updatedState = if (isStarting) {
            val startTime = displayTimeFormatter.format(Date())

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString(START_TIME_KEY, startTime).apply()
            }

            startTimer(context)
            currentState.copy(bottomSheetVisibility = false)
        } else {
            val endTime = displayTimeFormatter.format(Date())

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString(END_TIME_KEY, endTime).apply()
            }

            stopTimer(context)
            currentState.copy(bottomSheetVisibility = true)
        }

        _uiState.value = updatedState
    }
}

logcat exception:

E :  ANR in com.jtpl.project
(com.jtpl.project/.presentation.MainActivity)   PID: 20257   Reason:
Input dispatching timed out (d863c4a
com.jtpl.project/com.jtpl.sleeplikeababy.presentation.MainActivity
(server) is not responding. Waited 5002ms for
FocusEvent(hasFocus=false)). Parent:
com.jtpl.project/.presentation.MainActivity ErrorId:
b8443fce-5bba-4078-81ee-2d85417e44f3 Frozen: false Load: 1.51 / 0.48 /
0.29
---- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----

When start and stop timer for first time bottom sheet is not opening for second time its opening.
